# Intel Fortran Module Data Interop with C#

Tags: c#, fortran, intel-fortran, dllexport

Given the following Fortran module, I am trying to grab a reference to the variable A so that I can manipulate it directly in C#.

```
    module FortranLibrary
    use Sample_Data

    implicit none

    real(8) :: A
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: A
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: 'A' :: A

    contains

    SUBROUTINE GetA(value)
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: GetA
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: 'GetA' :: GetA
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: value

        REAL(8), INTENT(OUT) :: value

        value = A

    END SUBROUTINE GetA

    subroutine DoWork()

        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: DoWork
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: 'DoWork' :: DoWork

        A = 41

        return

    end subroutine DoWork

end module
```

If I call GetA, I get a value back rather than a reference (changing the variable on the C# side does not effect the Fortran variable and vice versa. If I call A, I get the following exception:

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

I can't say I'm surprised at that one because A is a data export and while I can clearly see it listed as a function in dependency walker, I have no idea what prototype that function would have or even if it is really a function or just an imperfect user interface in dependency walker.

Here is how I import those elements into C#:

```
[DllImport("FP1_Library.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void DoWork();
[DllImport("FP1_Library.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void GetA(ref double val);
[DllImport("FP1_Library.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void A(out double val);
```

Can someone help me export a reference to a module variable out to C#?

Comment: Google pinvoke().

Comment: I will keep reading about pinvoke, but can you tell me if it is possible to import a field into a C# app from a C++ dll?

Comment: The process of transferring data between native and .Net is known as `marshalling `. Also, an alternative to calling pinvoke from C# is writing another layer - C++/CLI DLL that  goes between your Fortran and C#.

Comment: Thanks, reading about marshalling has been helpful, and I am now able to pass values back and forth to a degree. There is still some real code smell because I am passing by reference, not by value and so should have a reference.

Comment: I've rewritten the question to hopefully be more clear and concrete.

Comment: In your crashing example, do not you need `ref double A` in the C# declaration of DoWork?

Comment: yes, that's exactly right. I found that just a few minutes ago and have updated my question. I thought that would get me where I needed, but it doesn't quite get me there. I need to be able to pass a module data member out to C#, not just a function member.

Comment: Why did you remove all args from the subroutine on the Fortran side???

Comment: There are two things going on. I split the original subroutine into two, one that returns the reference to A, and one that increments A. I have also tried both a function and a subroutine for GetA, but both seem to pass back a value rather than a reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201676/discussion-between-eugene-and-eric).

Comment: Change then calling convention to stdcall